# google embeded map renders broken sometimes

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-embed

Sometimes my map loads normally like this.

[image: Perfect Map]

and sometimes it loads this weirdly off-center broken world map like this

[image: Broken map]

Does anyone know why i sometimes get the broken map? and also, how can i fix it to always render the correct map?

Some background, I'm using AngularJs to create the src in the iframe.

**UPDATE**
Here's the HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="MapCtrl" class="left" id="interactiveMap">
        <iframe
          width="300"
          height="225"
          frameborder="0" style="border:0"
          ng-src={{map.url}}>
        </iframe>


    </div>
```

And the MapCtrl

```
(function () {
'use strict';

function MapCtrl($scope, $http, $sce, $timeout) {

    $scope.$parent.$watchCollection('business', function() { 
       $scope.getPreAddress()

       $timeout(function() {
           $scope.getMap()   
       },2000)


    },true)

    $scope.getPreAddress = function() {
        var preAddress = $scope.business.address1 + 
        " " + $scope.business.address2 + 
        ","+ $scope.business.city+ 
        " " + $scope.business.state + 
        " "+ $scope.business.zip

        return preAddress.replace(/ /g, "+")            
    }

    $scope.getMap = function() {
        $http.get("/src/json/map-keys.json").success(function(data){
            $scope.keys = data
            $scope.map = {
                url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key="+$scope.keys.google.google_key+"&q="+$scope.getPreAddress()+"&zoom=16")
            } 
        })                  
    }

 }
module.exports = MapCtrl
```

})()

Comment: The iframe needs to have a size when you load the map, it obviously doesn't have a  size at this time when it looks like the 2nd image

Comment: @Dr.Molle The height/width is hardcoded in the iframe. Is there a higher priority place to declare it? I think CSS loads after the html...

Comment: the relevant size is the real, calculated size. When the parent element is hidden at the moment when the iframe-src loads, the calculated size of the iframe is 0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interested parties.... The problem turned out to be that the HTML above is contained in a larger div that is hidden at first. Google embeded maps don't behave properly inside hidden divs. The solution was to push the div up really high to be hidden visually instead of literally.